# Why Odoo doesn't read extra fields added to a model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have created a module to add new fields to any model without the constraints of the built in way (like adding the `'x_'` prefix and setting the field `state` as custom).

When I create a view to show the newly added fields, I get the error: `"Field x does not exist in model y"`.

The newly added fields show up in the `Technical -> Models` view.

When I did some debugging I found that Odoo reads only the fields that are defined in the (.py) files.

How can I make it read the newly added fields?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you're adding the fields?

Comment: By invoking the "ir.model.fields" create method but change the behavior of adding the 'x_' prefix.

Comment: What do you mean by setting the `state` as custom? So far i know there are only two values: `base` and `manual`. You should stick with `manual`.